# How to include your run-time code in a main method in Python?

Tags: python, runtime, program-entry-point

This was asked at the end of a Python challenge. [Here is the link to the challenge][1]
I would really appreciate it if you could explain it to me or address me to documentation in this subject.
I have searched for it and I am not sure if the answers I came across are relevant to this question. Here is the most relevant code I found.

```
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    print(f"{time.time() - start_time} seconds")
```

My question is: is this what the exercise asked for? and if not, what is the answer?
[1]: https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/05/28/16-password-generator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that everything you write for this problem should be inside a `main()` function, like so:

```
def main():
    #some statements here
```